# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=nx^{n-1}$ on $[0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I wonder if there is a way to prove the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$, where $f_n(x)=nx^{n-1},0\le x<1$, to be uniformly convergent? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hint : it's not.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Augustin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converge pointwise to $0$, but
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1[}|f_n(x)|=n\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }+\infty $$
therefore it can't be uniformly convergent.

Comment: You want to say "can't be uniformly convergent"

Comment: @zhw.: yes, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, @Surb.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$\int_{[0,1)}f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_{[0,1)} nx^{n-1}\ \mathsf dx = 1 $$
for all $n$, but
$\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^{n-1}=0$
for all $x\in[0,1)$. Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1)}f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx \ne \int_{[0,1)}\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx, $$
we conclude that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Math1000.

Comment: I think if the domain is slightly modified as $0\le x<b<1$, then $f_n$ would be uniformly convergent.

Comment: @Sam That would just mean the integral of $f_n$ is $b$ instead of $1$.

Comment: I think it would be $b^n$. @Math1000

Comment: That's correct actually. So $f_n$ indeed converges uniformly on $[0,b)$ for all $0<b<1$.

Comment: Thank @Math1000 for clarification. BTW, I am curious whether $\{f_n\}$, where $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1},0\le x\le b<1$, is uniformly convergent or not.

Comment: That's a finite geometric sum so write it in closed form and consider $\sup_x|f_n(x)|$.